# Firebase - Angularjs handle email verification

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use firebase and Angularjs on my web app. I have a factory below serving to all my app modules:

```
.factory('Auth', ["$firebaseAuth",
    function($firebaseAuth) {
       return $firebaseAuth();
   }
]);
```

It is critical for me (in fact it is the easiest and only way I know) to check pages if auth required or not. So I put this code on each module config in $stateProvider :

```
resolve: {
    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        return Auth.$requireSignIn();
    }]
```

I want to use firebase email verification and according to [documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#create_the_email_action_handler_page) I need to do so:

```
var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var auth = app.auth();
...
function handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueUrl) {
  auth.applyActionCode(actionCode).then(function(resp) {
   ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
   ...
  });
}
```

But then it returns error:

> {code: "app/duplicate-app", message: "Firebase: Firebase App named
>   '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).",

I wanted to try with the factory `Auth.applyActionCode` but there is no such method. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: make sure you're not calling the initialize method more than once. see: https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/issues/16

Comment: ok. I have solved. yes the problem is that and I didn't know how to reach the functions already initialized app. I found now.  firebase.auth().applyActionCode;

Comment: great, added comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you're not calling the initialize method more than once. see: github.com/Polymer/polycasts/issues/16 for more details.